# Custom Multiple Column Combo Box into DataGridView ComboBox in C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want create a custom DataGridView Columns with this Properties :

1. Multi Columns Dropdown
2. Dropdown Show Data From Database ' %Like%'
3. ComboBox Columns is Typeable

can someone Guide and Help Me

Comment: this is in WinForms or WPF?

Comment: This is in Winforms

Comment: i this this article helpful for you: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/datagridview-autofilter-621f80f71b63

Comment: @MansurKurtov i want multicolumns datagridvies combobox